# Need to populate a dropdown with sharepoint groups in which am a member

Tags: 2010, groups

I have some groups in SharePoint application. I have a dropdown in visual webpart which is to be populated with only those SharePoint groups in which am added as user. 
Edit: I have added users in active directory in groups and have added those AD groups to  sharepoint groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope these links help you..

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/hec.ravi/display-sharepoint-users-groups-and-sites-in-a-gridview-and-use-a-dropdownlist-to-filter-the-values/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/get-all-the-site-groups-in-sharepoint-2010-using-ecma-script/

Thanks